# Citing sources "Adversity introduces a man to himself"

Tags: quotes, apa

This famous quote from Albert Einstein, after research, doesn't have any origins (No year, no location/event, etc.). How would you go about citing it in APA format?

Comment: Maybe it is simply made up.

Answer (score 4):

If there's no source for the quote, it's very likely misattributed. A lot of quotes get falsely attributed to Einstein, probably to give them a little more weight. Proper citation means that you don't propagate this false information, and in fact, do your best to set the record straight.

The [earliest references on Google books](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=703&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1900%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1950&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNTCPQt-TfMsuGOupHmphBkDvKmTiw%3A1579082470482&ei=5uIeXqOQHcjKwAL1-qboBw&q=%22adversity+introduces+a+man+to+himself%22&oq=%22adversity+introduces+a+man+to+himself%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...30111.30704.0.31350.2.2.0.0.0.0.42.82.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.ml1gKdDE0m4) are from around 1945 and attribute the saying to "Anonymous".

I'd attribute the quote to Anonymous and add a footnote saying something like:

> This saying is often credited to Albert Einstein, but there is no credible source for this attribution.

Comment: Remember the wise words of Abraham Lincoln: "Don't believe everything you read on the Internet".